# How can I define multiple alias names for a php class?

Tags: php, class, alias

this is my first question on this forum, glad to be here, hoping you can help

I'm trying to define multiple alias names for a single php class. I know class_alias() can be used to define an alias, but I only see that as working for a single alias, and for each new alias I'd have to repeat it for the new alias. I'm wondering if there's a way to give multiple aliases to a php class without having to repeat the command every time. I need this because my website automatically creates links to other parts of it when words with the name are found anywhere, and I want to be able to expand that to different words that mean the same thing, sort of how Wikipedia redirects similar words to the same entry. Does anyone know what can help me do this

Comment: I don't think class aliasses is the right solution for you. Why not keep a custom mapping, of aliasses to classes? You are allowed to do `$class = "MyClass"; $instance = new $class();` in PHP.

Comment: You could create a function that accepts an array of aliases and then calls the `class_alias` function multiple times. Then each time you'd be able to make one call to your function.